# Could not initialize class net.liftweb.json.DefaultFormats$

Tags: json, scala, case-class, lift-json

I am working in Scala programming language and I am trying to generate `json` from 
 a `case class`.

I am following instructions on [this](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/scala-cookbook/9781449340292/ch15s02.html) page. I have added dependency in `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.liftweb</groupId>
    <artifactId>lift-json-scalaz7_2.12</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

The code that I have in my worksheet is

```
import net.liftweb.json._
import net.liftweb.json.Serialization.write

case class Person(name: String, address: Address)
case class Address(city: String, state: String)

val p = Person("Alvin Alexander", Address("Talkeetna", "AK"))
implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
val jsonString = write(p)
println(jsonString)
```

I get exception: "`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class net.liftweb.json.DefaultFormats$`"

what could be wrong here?

Thanks